# Can we use online video lectures to free university professors from lecturing for lower-division courses in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, teaching, professorship, university

During the 2020-2021 Covid-19 season, universities and colleges around the world made most of their math classes online over Zoom and many professors have their recorded lectures.

Most math lectures usually don't involve in-class discussions and for the most of the time, professors dominates the teaching. Oftentimes, *excellent recorded lectures can be much better than live lectures in mathematics and other theoretical sciences*. I have seen many students commenting under certain YouTube videos that those recorded lectures are much better than their professors'.

I wonder if we could possibly use those recorded videos (there are a lot of such videos modulo-necessary-editing during Covid-19 season. Building a system like (https://nptel.ac.in/) should be feasible) to free university math professors from *repeatedly giving lectures on lower-division math classes* like calculus, linear algebra or differential equations (but at the same time, asking them to hold discussion sessions and office hours to have *more* interactions with students and of course, grading homework assignments and exams), so that they could have more time on their research and teaching classes that are  more relevant to their research? I believe this is particularly important for the early-career mathematicians. Many postdocs in math are assigned with lower division classes that are kind-of digressions to their research.

This seems to be a win-win strategy for both professors and students in terms of the mathematics. If this is good then maybe it should have been conducted already like https://nptel.ac.in/. What would be the potential challenges for doing so for higher education in United States and Europe?

Comment: I think this would most likely lead to greatly reduced sizes of math departments... Automated by playing those videos over and over. And, yes, many students might rightly be happier with good videos in comparison to dubious live lectures...

Comment: Can we? Yes. Should we? Harder to say. But this looks like a call for opinion only. Hard to say how less interaction between students and professors can be called a win for anyone.

Comment: @paulgarrett Well, math departments are funded by tax payers after all. The government should know what to do, I guess? We need mathematicians not just for their teaching.

Comment: @Buffy I hope the last sentence in my post would make this question less opinion-based

Comment: @NoOne, I agree that "teaching calculus" is not the only function of mathematicians, but from an all-too-common viewpoint of university administrations, a way to reduce costs of "covering" calculus would be highly desirable. The other parts are toooo intangible. :)

Comment: And your last paragraph starts with an opinion. Before you think about "how" to do so, settle the question of "why".  Color me skeptical. No single explanation of a concept will "reach" every student. Flexibility is needed. Replaying a video with the same explanation repeated will be sub-optimal. Some will be fine. Others not. One thing beginning teachers need to learn is that answering a question with exactly the same explanation is not going to be successful. That is why the question was asked.

Comment: 'Most math lectures usually don't involve in-class discussions and the for the most of the time, professors dominates the teaching.'  That may be true as an observation, but the bits of the peer-reviewed literature on higher education pedagogy in which I've dabbled suggest it's not true as a guide to best practice.

Comment: @Buffy Well, this is a question that I want to ask for years but haven't thought of a way to perfectly avoid the "opinion-based" tag.

Comment: @Buffy "Replaying a video with the same explanation repeated will be sub-optimal". This can be address by professors holding discussion sessions and offices hours. If they are free from lecturing, they would have more time and energy for that.

Comment: @Buffy "One thing beginning teachers need to learn is that answering a question with exactly the same explanation is not going to be successful" I believe nowadays new teacher, aka postdocs, need more time for their research just in order to SURVIVE in academia... If there are already nice video lectures recorded by experienced teachers, why do we still need to ask young mathematicians' to spend so much time on teaching?

Comment: But consider the time delay between the time the question arises and the first opportunity to get it answered. And it would be more chaotic, with only the one asking the question hearing the answer. Often if one student has a question, others have it also, but aren't "brave" enough to ask. Not a good plan.

Comment: Among other things, teaching gives you additional insight into your subject. Efficiency and effectiveness are not friends here.

Comment: @Buffy "But consider the time delay between the time the question arises and the first opportunity to get it answered". (You comments seem to make it more necessary for me to add explanations on "how".) Yes, this is an issue. But recored videos can be edited. If a student want to see some certain details about L-Hospital's rule or more clarifications on Jordan normal form, professor can add explanations to the original video through editing.

Comment: @Buffy "Among other things, teaching gives you additional insight into your subject. Efficiency and effectiveness are not friends here." Yes, but as an algebraic geometer or number theorist , a person may want to spend more time teaching algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory or at least abstract algebra, rather than calculus and linear algebra...

Comment: @NoOne, universities need far fewer people giving courses on higher mathematics than on calculus. You want math depts of 5 faculty + thousands of hours of videos?

Comment: @paulgarrett Then it would be the government's duty to provide math departments enough grant to maintain enough number of mathematicians... Providing adequate funding to fundamental research should be in the radar of lawmakers...

Comment: "Then it would be the government's duty..." Ha. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes, you absolutely can!](https://mobile.twitter.com/AaronLinguini/status/1352009211501289472)

The win-win is very unlikely though. Students won't see lower tuition or anything, and will have no opportunity to interact with anyone at the faculty level (so no letters of recommendation, no research jobs, etc). Professor lines will be closed on retirement (or through layoffs) because who needs them, we've got McGraw-Hill eLectures.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this is probably an accurate assessment, given my own experience with university administrations.

Comment: "and will have no opportunity to interact with anyone at the faculty level ".... I did add some sentences about this issue (paragraph #3). Professors will hold discussion sessions and offices hours to increase their interactions with students. University administrations can make it a policy that students must go to discussion sessions as attendance requirement ...

Comment: That's a nice idea. A grad student TA is cheaper. We can even get the students to pay for the course kit though a textbook code. Guess what wins between nice and cheap?

Comment: @Libor This will be another issue that worths another question "why tuition and fees in U.S is so expensive" (which is not the case in many other countries, though)

Comment: @NoOne, other countries are more willing to spend tax receipts on education. Education is expensive since it is labor intensive and professors want a decent salary. Your plan would save money, I suppose, but at the expense of quality and ultimately at the expense of the future itself. Saving money isn't the end all and be all. Look to the recent disaster in Texas, for example.

Comment: @Buffy  I want to emphasize that my question (not this answer and its comments) is not really about saving money, but about saving time for mathematicians by avoiding repeated labor. But I will think about your comments more deeply, though. Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't but every administration is - so this thing you're suggesting is happening, will only grow, and will not be in any way designed or implemented as you hope.